Why is reliability a ratio of true score variance to total score variance, instead of the ratio of true score to total score?
Reliability is given by:
$r_{xx} = \frac{Var(T)}{Var(X)}$
where $T$ is the true score and $X$ is the total score.
Why isn't reliability simply:
$r_{xx} = \frac{T}{X}$
where $T$ would be a sum of all the individual true scores and $X$ would be the sum of all individual total scores?

$E(X) = T$, so you would always get a ratio close to 1.0 regardless of the error structure. So pretty useless as a measure of reliability.

Not if the measurement is biased.

@PeterFlom of course, though even if biased $T/X$ wouldn't be a measure of reliability, which was OPs question. That's the point I was expressing

$\frac{T}{X}$ might be a measure of bias, but it can't be a measure of reliability.
If the measured score is consistently  too high or too low, then that's bias, which is part of validity. Briefly, validity asks whether we are measuring what we think we are measuring, reliability is how consistently we are measuring whatever it is we are measuring. Suppose you have three ordinary scales. First, you weigh yourself on a gold standard scale. 60 kg.  Then you get on and off each one 5 times.
Scale a:  55 55  55  55 56
Scale b:  55 65 55 65 60
Scale b is less biased but less reliable.
